# merging data frames results in identical duplicated rows

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have a curious problem while doing some very basic data manipulations. I have a data frame (**dat**) consisting of information about different plots (identified by plot_id) which are resampled from time to time. In another data frame, I have the coordinates of the exact same plots. The goal is to merely add the coordinates to my original data frame **dat**. However, when I do so, all entries/ rows of **dat** double and even when I try to delete the identical rows afterwards, this doesn't work.

I guess it has to be some kind of problem with the data structure, but I never came across this issue before.

```
# merging coordinates to dat
dat_merged <- left_join(dat, coord, by = "plot_id")

# attempt to delete the duplicated rows
dat_merged_distinct <- distinct(dat_merged)
```

Subset of the data I use:

```
dat <- structure(list(plot_id = c("CLC.LP.04.2", "CLC.LP.06.2", "CLC.LP.01.2", 
"CLC.LP.03.3", "CLC.LP.02.3", "CLC.LP.03.3", "CLC.LP.02.2", "CLC.LP.03.2", 
"CLC.LP.02.2", "CLC.LP.03.2", "CLC.LP.02.3", "CLC.LP.03.3", "CLC.LP.02.3", 
"CLC.LP.04.3", "CLC.LP.03.2"), Region = c("CLC", "CLC", "CLC", 
"CLC", "CLC", "CLC", "CLC", "CLC", "CLC", "CLC", "CLC", "CLC", 
"CLC", "CLC", "CLC"), Cover = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Abundance = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Year = c(2007L, 2017L, 
2007L, 2017L, 2017L, 2007L, 2017L, 2012L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2007L, 2017L), sp_name = c("Viviania marifolia", 
"Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", 
"Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", 
"Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", 
"Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia", 
"Viviania marifolia", "Viviania marifolia")), row.names = 26053:26067, class = "data.frame")

coord <- structure(list(plot_id = c("CLC.LP.01.1", "CLC.LP.01.2", "CLC.LP.01.3", 
"CLC.LP.02.1", "CLC.LP.02.2", "CLC.LP.02.3", "CLC.LP.03.1", "CLC.LP.03.2", 
"CLC.LP.03.3", "CLC.LP.04.1", "CLC.LP.04.2", "CLC.LP.04.3", "CLC.LP.05.1", 
"CLC.LP.06.1", "CLC.LP.06.2", "CLC.LP.06.3", "CLC.LP.07.1", "CLC.LP.07.2", 
"CLC.LP.07.3", "CLC.LP.08.1", "CLC.LP.08.2", "CLC.LP.08.3", "CLC.LP.09.1", 
"CLC.LP.09.2", "CLC.LP.09.3", "CLC.LP.02.1", "CLC.LP.02.2", "CLC.LP.02.3", 
"CLC.LP.03.1", "CLC.LP.03.2", "CLC.LP.03.3", "CLC.LP.04.1", "CLC.LP.04.2", 
"CLC.LP.04.3", "CLC.LP.06.1", "CLC.LP.06.2", "CLC.LP.06.3", "CLC.LP.07.1", 
"CLC.LP.07.2", "CLC.LP.07.3", "CLC.LP.08.1", "CLC.LP.08.2", "CLC.LP.08.3", 
"CLC.LP.09.1", "CLC.LP.09.2", "CLC.LP.09.3"), lat = c(-33.34875, 
-33.34875, -33.34875, -33.35455556, -33.35455556, -33.35455556, 
-33.35775, -33.35775, -33.35775, -33.35533333, -33.35533333, 
-33.35533333, -33.352, -33.34263889, -33.34263889, -33.34263889, 
-33.34008333, -33.34008333, -33.34008333, -33.33033333, -33.33033333, 
-33.33033333, -33.33116667, -33.33116667, -33.33116667, -33.354556, 
-33.354556, -33.354556, -33.35775, -33.35775, -33.35775, -33.355333, 
-33.355333, -33.355333, -33.342639, -33.342639, -33.342639, -33.340083, 
-33.340083, -33.340083, -33.330333, -33.330333, -33.330333, -33.331167, 
-33.331167, -33.331167), long = c(-70.33175, -70.33175, -70.33175, 
-70.32769444, -70.32769444, -70.32769444, -70.32772222, -70.32772222, 
-70.32772222, -70.32013889, -70.32013889, -70.32013889, -70.31002778, 
-70.29636111, -70.29636111, -70.29636111, -70.29172222, -70.29172222, 
-70.29172222, -70.28611111, -70.28611111, -70.28611111, -70.28169444, 
-70.28169444, -70.28169444, -70.327694, -70.327694, -70.327694, 
-70.327722, -70.327722, -70.327722, -70.320139, -70.320139, -70.320139, 
-70.296361, -70.296361, -70.296361, -70.291722, -70.291722, -70.291722, 
-70.286111, -70.286111, -70.286111, -70.281694, -70.281694, -70.281694
)), row.names = c(92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 
646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 
657L, 658L, 659L, 660L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hey, Em. You data is distinct. R shows you just the first 5 digits after the comma, but there are actually more (see in your post). -33.35533333 is -33.35533 , etc. So the data is distinct. Your long/lat is so detailled that R is dropping the accuracy for reporting purpose.

Comment: Wow, that's an easy solution indeed, I should have checked that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can  try the following code as a solution:

```
coord <- coord %>% distinct(plot_id, .keep_all = T)
dat1 <- dat %>% left_join(coord)
```